# it is still adding the row as i am using the last_insert_id function on dupliacte key for updating

Tags: php, mysql

```
insert into transaction(account_name,dates,debit,credit)
 values('$account_name',curdate(),$debit,$credit)
   on duplicate key 
 update last_insert_id(account_id) debit=values($debit),credit=values($credit)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think for [Duplicate key](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html) you need try this code:

```
INSERT INTO transaction(account_name,dates,debit,credit)
VALUES('$account_name',curdate(),$debit,$credit)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE debit=VALUES(debit), credit=VALUES(credit)
```

Comment: If this query don't work - please provide your database dump.

Comment: Also make sure that you set your primary key or unique index... check the link in alexey palamar's post for more info.

Comment: the account_id is AUTO_INCREMENT i have used last_insert_id still it's adding a row

Comment: But this query not contain `account_id `, I think you wrong understand how to use "ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE". This feature need only if you have some uniq key. As example you need create uniq key for `account_name` then your query will work as you expect.

Comment: thnks :) i have done it